# Notify other user to accept the video call initiated by user one (Video call by jitsi-meet from Rocket Chat)

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, rocket.chat, jitsi

We are trying to integrate Jitsi Video calling in Rocket chat, we succeeded to integrate the Jitsi SDK in Rocket chat, For that i have taken one button on chat window of rocket chat on tapping of which user navigating to Jitsi's video view controller,

My problem is what, suppose 'user 1' and 'user 2' are chatting and 'user 1' want to have a video call with 'user 2' and for that he tap on video button then 'user 2' should get the video call invitation to accept it and start the video conference.

The Web's Rocket chat app has the video button already on chat window of Rocket chat and also Web's Rocket chat has provided the settings from Admin's account to set the video call URL and room id names etc. so in web app of Rocket chat if 'user 1' taps on video button 'user 2' gets the invitation with 'Click to join' button in chat and video conference get starts in same window by tapping on button 'Click to join'..

As in iOS Rocket chat we dont have any default video button or any settings like web to allow the Jitsi video call to have confernce for users who are chatting, I took my own video button and landed user to next viewController and did the set up as per Jitsi's install guid,
Which works for static Room ids, but i want it to work for different different users of different different sessions/logins..

Is there any thing is there in mobile Rocket chat to support Jitsi video calling like Web's Rocket chat..? Or how can i achieve the same functionality like web's Rocket chat+Jitsi in Mobile Rocket chat.

**I have been searching for same thing from more than a week of time, But not able to get anything for native iOS, yes there are lot of things available for Desktop RocketChat + Jitsi, but i didnt get anything for native iOS...**

Please.. Your any help will be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution to get alert of call? It will be very helpful if it is figured out. I want to implement it in react-native for android for now.